# Single postback on a page being called by another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Here's the scenario:
[image]

My source page needs to call target page to check if it is existing. It can sometimes any page in the application or some page outside. Now in the scenario that it is calling one of the pages in the application, doing a postback on the target page twice might cause some performance issue due to its processing (This I understand because of the `GET` method).

Is there a way that the target page would have one postback when being called from the source page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below,

```
<form method="post" action="YourPage.aspx">
  <h1>Page passing tests</h1>
  <p>Please enter some data in the field below and click send</p>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" placeholder="enter text here" />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSend">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this in the target page or source page?

Comment: Target page. In source page, you need to put code like this.